# Question about present perfect and past simple

Tags: present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I have a question concerning the present perfect and the simple  simple.

Talking about the story of a family, which of the following statements is correct:

1. My aunt has found a new job in Melbourne so they moved there.
2. My aunt found a new job in Melbourne so they moved there.

As the fact of finding a job has an effect on the present, I would say the first one is correct. On the other hand, there is a mismatch between the two tenses. Can you suggest which statement is correct and which one is incorrect?

Comment: The fact of finding a job _may have_ effect on the 'present' ... "My aunt found a new job in Melbourne so she and my niece moved there. Later, they moved back here to Sydney again." //  "My aunt has found a new job in Melbourne, so they have moved there."  As an aside, note that it is the 'effective', ie at time of speaking, present.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer.

Comment: I used a 'comment' to answer because I'm pretty sure (1) this has one or more duplicate and (2) it would take me 30 minutes + to find it/them.

Comment: @Edwin: Yes; a comma before 'so' is important. What do you think about "My aunt found a new job in Melbourne, so they have moved there"? Finding the job happened (a clear simple past); and moving followed, say very recently...?

Comment: It's not verboten to leave it out, but where commas are optional, I use them to indicate a short pause (which often also applies when they _are_ needed to say disambiguate, set off). It would be purely for stress in that example (and for more stress [moving to Melbourne! Wow!] an ellipsis.

Comment: Nota Bene: You should write 'I have a question concerning the following'. Saying 'I have a doubt concerning the following' sounds strange in English. This is a common error of speakers of romance languages, and also of Indian.

Comment: Ah, but which is more accurate?

Answer (score 2):

Either is good, but the clauses must agree.  Note commas.

1. My aunt has found a new job in Melbourne, so they **have** moved there.
2. My aunt found a new job in Melbourne, so they moved there.

Sentence #1 suggests recent time.

Comment: Sentence two is fine: simple past tense in both clauses. There has to be a reason for using the present perfect rather than the simple past. The first sentence conveys no more than the second. If the sentence were "My aunt has found a new job in Melbourne, so she will move there," then the sentence has a meaning different from the simple past.